# Heroku doesn't run Rails app from Hartl's Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm at the [end of section 5 of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec%3alayout_conclusion), my app works in development but when I type:

```
heroku open
```

I get the standard "We're sorry, but something went wrong." When I type:

```
heroku logs
```

I get (abbreviated, I've selected the relevant output, it appears three times with slight differences):

```
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML

Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>

ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after " *": expected "{", was "= require_self"

2: <html>

   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
```

My application.css file is unaltered and entirely commented out.

Any ideas on what the problem is?  I have a gemfile with `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'` in it.

Comment: Your assets dont seem to be getting compiled

Answer (score 0):

If there is a *= require_self in your css, I would guess it means your assets didn't compile.

I'd double-check your stylesheets, and remember you generally should not put any actual css in the application.css file.

Also, Im pretty sure Rails compiles all your stylesheets into one big stylesheet for production, which means if there is an issue in one of them the whole thing might have issues.

Thats all i got- its a bizarre error because css is usually very forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

```
/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

You've got two **/app** directories in the path.  To verify, run

```
rails console
> Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```